# Why is the <p> element text overlapping on itself

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in the snippet, the `<p>` element is overlapping over itself for some reason and not going to a new line when it is supposed to. I'm not sure what is causing this. The way I thought it would work is that the parent element of the `<p>` element would increase in height based on the height of the p element.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
body {
    background-color: #F7F4EB;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.gallery-container {
    font-size: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.gallery-element {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33333%;
}
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.information {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.company-info {
    display: flex;
}
.who-us, .about-us {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
            <div class="gallery-container">
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                    <p class='information'>
                        We can install a variety of different washing machines including front loading machines, top loading machines and also washer dryer machines.
                        Our installation service include all safety checks to ensure there is no leak potential.
                        We provide a dishwasher installation service that ensures the machine is working efficiently.
                        We check that the electrical and plumbing connections in the house are safe and make certain there will be no potential for leaks.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                    <p class='information'>
                        We can install a variety of different washing machines including front loading machines, top loading machines and also washer dryl and plumbing connections in the house are safe and make certain there will be no potential for leaks.
                    </p>
                </div>
                                <div class="gallery-element">
                <img class='responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                <p class='information'>
                    We can install a variety of different washing machines including front loading machines, top loading machines and also washer dryer machines.
                    Our installation service include all safety checks to ensure there is no leak potential.
                    We provide a dishwasher installation service that ensures the machine is working efficiently.
                    We check that the electrical and plumbing connections in the house are safe and make certain there will be no potential for leaks.
                </p>
            </div>
                            <div class="gallery-element">
                <img class='responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                <p class='information'>
                    We can install a variety of different washing machines including front loading machines, top loading machines and also washer dryer machines.
                    Our installation service include all safety checks to ensure there is no leak potential.
                    We provide a dishwasher installation service that ensures the machine is working efficiently.
                    We check that the electrical and plumbing connections in the house are safe and make certain there will be no potential for leaks.
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Because you have `line-height: 0;` on `.gallery-container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be from the line-height of 0 on the wrapping `div.gallery-container`.  Remove that line or change to a normal value like 1 or 1.4.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
body {
    background-color: #F7F4EB;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.gallery-container {
    font-size: 0px;
    /* REMOVED */
    /* line-height: 0; */
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.gallery-element {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33333%;
}
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.information {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.company-info {
    display: flex;
}
.who-us, .about-us {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
            <div class="gallery-container">
                <div class="gallery-element">
                    <img class='responsive' src="https://i.imgur.com/wMkl3hm.jpg" alt="">
                    <p class='information'>
                        We can install a variety of different washing machines including front loading machines, top loading machines and also washer dryer machines.
                        Our installation service include all safety checks to ensure there is no leak potential.
                        We provide a dishwasher installation service that ensures the machine is working efficiently.
                        We check that the electrical and plumbing connections in the house are safe and make certain there will be no potential for leaks.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove  `font-size: 0px; line-height: 0;` from `.gallery-container`